# Laravel API get categories with posts only

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have API resource and i call it in my API controller so it returns my data, I am in need of adding one extra filter into this API but I'm not sure how?

#### What I need

1. Get categories which has post only.
2. Exclude categories without post of the results.

#### What I have

1. List of all categories with and without posts.

## Code

`Resource`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use App\Http\Resources\PostResource;

class CategoryResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'image' => url('images', $this->photo),
            'url' => $this->slug,
            'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts')),
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\CategoryResource;
use App\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $categories = CategoryResource::collection(Category::where('status', '1')->with('posts')->orderby('id', 'desc')->get());
        return response()->json($categories);
    }
}
```

**Any idea how to add that filter in my controller?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the categories where they have at least one post using `has` function like so:

```
Category::where('status', '1')->with('posts')->has('posts')->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
```